# kafka is failing to start because cluster/id is deleted from Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Apache Kafka is failing to start. It shows in its logs "Failed to get cluster id from Zookeeper. This can happen if /cluster/id is deleted from Zookeeper."

How can I check the "/cluster/id"?

previously, when kafka is failing to start it is because I updated java on my server. So, I need to re-direct $JAVA_HOME to the new path & restart kafka and it will work again just fine. But, this case is different, I checked $JAVA_HOME & it's correct. So, I wanted to know more details of this issue. I read one of the logs file in `/opt/kafka/logs` and I got this log:

```
[2019-08-21 10:18:40,472] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to get cluster id from Zookeeper. This can happen if /cluster/id is deleted from Zookeeper.
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createOrGetClusterId$1(KafkaZkClient.scala:1498)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createOrGetClusterId(KafkaZkClient.scala:1498)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.$anonfun$getOrGenerateClusterId$1(KafkaServer.scala:390)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.getOrGenerateClusterId(KafkaServer.scala:390)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:208)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2019-08-21 10:18:40,476] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2019-08-21 10:18:40,488] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-21 10:18:40,500] INFO Session: 0x100494a8714000a closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-21 10:18:40,505] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x100494a8714000a (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-21 10:18:40,507] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-21 10:18:40,517] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2019-08-21 10:18:40,517] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2019-08-21 10:18:40,554] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

when I read the previous Error

```
Failed to get cluster id from Zookeeper. This can happen if /cluster/id is deleted from Zookeeper.
```

I though that "zookeeper id" in this path was deleted by mistake `/tmp/zookeeper/myid` but the file is still there with the corresponding server number written in it & zk is working fine. my kafka version is 2.2.0 .

I searched online for this ERROR "Failed to get cluster id from Zookeeper. This can happen if /cluster/id is deleted from Zookeeper."

but honestly, I did not find any thing helpful.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the myid file, which is specific to zookeeper. Cluster ID is a Kafka related data, created during Kafka cluster startup. 
Can you afford wiping your zk data and restart everything?

Comment: Thank you very much @Yannick.

Here is what I did:

1. Go to `kafka/config/zookeeper/zookeeper.properties` , just to know your zk data directory. In my case, it’s `/tmp/zookeeper`
2. In`/tmp/zookeeper`, I found a directory named “version-2” which has some files such as (acceptedEpoch,  currentEpoch … etc)
3. I stopped zookeeper then I deleted version-2 directory.
4. I started zookeeper again.
5. Then, I started kafka agin. It works for me!

I have one final question, is this way will have an impact on kafka data such as (topics or messages …etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes this can have an impact on Kafka cause  topics metadata are stored in zk ( and other Kafka cluster metadata as well)

Comment: @Yannick . Is there another way to overcome this issue without impacting kafka data?

Comment: It depends, unfortunately this would need more clarification on how this happened. As I said, wiping data from zk is a quick and not super clean solution( just in a test environment) . I don't know any reason for loosing the cluster ID metadata from zk, so I just think that maybe several parts of your zk datas might got deleted thus a clean solution would require ' what exactly got deleted from your zk cluster, and why?'